# CSS|Bootstrap - Full-height column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I tried to set full-height column but something is bad (I need to stay with max-width on sidebar)

Here is my code:
CSS:

```
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}
.Sidebar {
    background: red;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    max-width: 330px;
    display: block;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 Sidebar">
      <!-- CONTENT -->
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-8">
      <!-- CONTENT -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x8ddug40/)

Comment: Your `.Sidebar` is in full-height already and it has 100% height of its parent's height. What's the problem again?

Comment: @choz I want to set full-height of page

Answer (score 4):

You need to set the height to 100**vh** instead of **%**. This sets it to 100% of the viewport instead of 100% of the content.

```
.Sidebar {
    background: red;
    height: 100vh;
    max-width: 330px;
    display: block;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x8ddug40/1/)

Comment: That assumes that  the page will never be longer than the viewport

Comment: This is one way to achieve it. Or he can also set the full-width for `.Sidebar` parents, which are `.container` and `.row`...

Comment: All very true, this is just one option for him to use.

Comment: It's fine - but now I using navbar and I getting scroll (this adding height of navbar) - how to remove it? https://jsfiddle.net/x8ddug40/2/

Comment: You could set the height to calc(100vh - 52px); (basically subtract the height of the nav bar from the calculation.) https://jsfiddle.net/x8ddug40/3/ You may want to follow @choz's advice though because if the user has to scroll the div will be shorter than the content.

Comment: I meant a full-height on `.container` and `.row`.. It's a typo.. :(

Comment: So I added `.container-fluid,
.row {
 height: 100%; min-height: 100%;
}` and it's not working ... https://jsfiddle.net/x8ddug40/4/

Comment: Remove the `height: 100%` from `body, html` and put a `min-height: 100vh` inside `.Sidebar`.